# Copy every nth line from one sheet to another

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 1 column, 700 rows. I care about every seventh line. I don't want to have to go in and delete the 6 rows between each row I care about. So my solution was to create another sheet and specify a reference to each cell I want.

```
=sheet1!a1
=sheet1!a8
=sheet1!a15
```

But I don't want to type in each of these formulas ... `100 times.I thought if I selected the three and dragged the box around, it would understand what I was trying to do, but no luck.

Any ideas on how to do this elegantly/efficiently?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In A1 of your new sheet, put this:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(ROW()-1)*7,0)
```

... and copy down. If you start somewhere other than row 1, change ROW() to ROW(A1) or some other cell on row 1, then copy down again.

If you want to copy the nth line but multiple columns, use the formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!A$1,(ROW()-1)*7,0)
```

This can be copied right too.

Comment: How can this queston be viewed 104k+ times, but this answer only get 50 upvotes? I demand an investigation.

Comment: @JeromyFrench Probably because it doesn't work? At least not on my version of Excel.

Comment: works for me, had 5000 gps coords from a path, way too much detail - just needed 50 points - worked like a charm!

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion the answers given to this question are too specific. Here's an attempt at a more general answer with two different approaches and a complete example.

#### The `OFFSET` approach

`OFFSET` takes 3 mandatory arguments. The first is a given cell that we want to offset from. The next two are the number of rows and columns we want to offset (downwards and rightwards). `OFFNET` returns the content of the cell this results in. For instance, `OFFSET(A1, 1, 2)` returns the contents of cell `C2` because `A1` is cell `(1,1)` and if we add `(1,2)` to that we get `(2,3)` which corresponds to cell `C2`.

To get this to return every nth row from another column, we can make use of the `ROW` function. When this function is given no argument, it returns the row number of the current cell. We can thus combine `OFFSET` and `ROW` to make a function that returns every nth cell by adding a multiplier to the value returned by `ROW`. For instance `OFFSET(A$1,ROW()*3,0)`. Note the use of `$1` in the target cell. If this is not used, the offsetting will offset from different cells, thus in effect adding `1` to the multiplier.

#### The `ADDRESS` + `INDIRECT` approach

`ADDRESS` takes two integer inputs and returns the address/name of the cell as a string. For instance, `ADDRESS(1,1)` return `"$A$1"`. `INDIRECT` takes the address of a cell and returns the contents. For instance, `INDIRECT("A1")` returns the contents of cell `A1` (it also accepts input with `$`'s in it). If we use `ROW` inside `ADDRESS` with a multiplier, we can get the address of every nth cell. For instance, `ADDRESS(ROW(), 1)` in row 1 will return `"$A$1"`, in row 2 will return `"$A$2"` and so on. So, if we put this inside `INDIRECT`, we can get the content of every nth cells. For instance, `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1*ROW()*3,1))` returns the contents of every 3rd cell in the first column when dragged downwards.

#### Example

Consider the following screenshot of a spreadsheet. The headers (first row) contains the call used in the rows below.
[image]
Column `A` contains our example data. In this case, it's just the positive integers (the counting continues outside the shown area). These are the values that we want to get every 3rd of, that is, we want to get 1, 4, 7, 10, and so on.

Column `B` contains an incorrect attempt at using the `OFFSET` approach but where we forgot to use `$`. As can be seen, while we multiply by `3`, we actually get every 4th row.

Column `C` contains an incorrect attempt at using the `OFFSET` approach where we remembered to use `$`, but forgot to subtract. So while we do get every 3rd value, we skipped some values (1 and 4).

Column `D` contains a correct function using the `OFFSET` approach.

Column `E` contains an incorrect attempt at using the `ADDRESS` + `INDRECT` approach, but where we forgot to subtract. Thus we skipped some rows initially. The same problem as with column `C`.

Column `F` contains a correct function using the `ADDRESS` + `INDRECT` approach.

Answer (score 11):

If I were confronted with extracting every 7th row I would “insert” a column before Column “A” . I would then (assuming that there is a header row in row 1)  type in the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in rows 2,3,4,5,6,7,8, I would highlight the 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and paste that block to the end of the sheet (700 rows worth). The result will be 1,23,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7…….   Now do a data sort ascending on column  “A”. After the sort all of the 1’s will be the first in the series, all of the 7’s will be the seventh item.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Straightforward and avoids macros... something that I should have specified. The offset solution was a bit more elegant, but this approach would have been just peachy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

insert a new column and put a series in 1,2,3,4, etc. Then create another new column and use the command =if(int(a1/7)=(a1/7),1,0) you should get a 1 in every 7th row, filter the column on the 1

Answer (score 3):

Highlight the 7th line.  Paintbrush the format for the first 7 lines a few times.  Then do a bigger chunk of paintbrush copying the format until you are done.  Every 7th line should be highlighted.  Filter by color and then copy and paste (paste the values) from the highlighted cells into a new sheet.

Comment: A very creative way which can be very helpful in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Create a macro and use the following code to grab the data and put it in a new sheet (Sheet2):

```
Dim strValue As String
Dim strCellNum As String
Dim x As String
x = 1

For i = 1 To 700 Step 7
    strCellNum = "A" & i
    strValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strCellNum).Value
    Debug.Print strValue
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & x).Value = strValue
    x = x + 1
Next
```

Let me know if this helps!
JFV

Comment: Looks like it'd work. I should have specified that I would prefer to avoid macros. Thanks for the submission... next time I'll have to dust off my VBA book to consider solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If your original data is in column form with multiple columns and the first entry of your original data in C42, and you want your new (down-sampled) data to be in column form as well, but only every seventh row, then you will also need to subtract out the row number of the first entry, like so:

```
=OFFSET(C$42,(ROW(C42)-ROW(C$42))*7,0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add new column and fill it with ascending numbers. Then filter by ([column] mod 7 = 0) or something like that (don't have Excel in front of me to actually try this);

If you can't filter by formula, add one more column and use the formula =MOD([column; 7]) in it then filter zeros and you'll get  all seventh rows.