# Excel INDEX Function with Row Function

Tags: excel

[image: Flare Data]

In the screenshot provided, I am trying to extract all of the flow data into one column by itself.  I got started using the INDEX function, but I believe I am missing something.  In the screenshot, cell G2 should contain the value "998", which it does.  Starting from cell C8, flow values occur every 14 rows in that column, so I want to write a function that when I copy and paste starts looking at cell C8 and returns the value every 14 rows.  What I have so far is this:

```
    =INDEX(C8:C354528, ROW(C1)+14)
```

This is close, because it does return me the value "998", but going forward, it basically moves my array selection down by one and the counts 14 rows...not what I want.

As an example, the next two values after "1000" should be, 998 and 992.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question properly, you can re-purpose and modify this answer here to suit your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211062/copy-every-nth-line-from-one-sheet-to-another (you'd obviously need to change 7 to 14 and $A$1 to $C$8). Just note that OFFSET is a volatile formula, so this can deliver a bit of a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a second helper column, you can use this Array formula to find such rows.  Note that this has a benefit in that your rows can be in any order - you aren't relying on the fact that "Flow" data is exactly X rows apart.

In Column I, let's say, in `I1`, you can put this:
`=IFERROR(SEARCH(" Flow ",$B1),"")`.

Then, where you want to keep your Flow numbers, you can use this array formula:

`=INDEX($C$1:$C$100,SMALL(IF($I$1:$I$100<>"",ROW($C$1:$C$100)-ROW($C$1)+1),ROWS($C$1:C1)))`
(enter using <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
=INDEX(C:C,8+(ROW(1:1)-1)*14)
```

And copy/drag down.

As stated in the comments OFFSET is volatile and should be avoided when possible.  INDEX() is not volatile.

Comment: Yeah, I did this and took a look through the data and found out that unfortunately, the flow data isn't spaced out evenly.  The answer below addresses that but is a little confusing for me.  In this case, it turns out the solution was painfully simple and I was trying to make it more complicated.  Just use "Filter" on column B and only show results for "LFG Flow".