# how to copy consecutive and skip n- lines in csv?

Tags: csv, sorting, cmd, skip

I have csv files per year, f.i. hourdata-2019.csv,
it looks like this:

```
date,hour,temp
20181231,24,75
20190101,1,76
20190101,2,76
20190101,3,75
20190101,4,76
20190101,5,74
......etc
```

what i would like to do is create a new file that has blocks of 2 consecutive lines and then skip some lines.
F.I. I would like to know the temp difference for one hour per every 9 hours throughout the year, so if I skip 7 lines the new file should look something like:

```
20190101,1,76
20190101,2,76
20190101,10,57
20190101,11,60
20190101,19,61
20190101,20,56
.........etc
```

I was first hoping that i could use OpenOffice or LibreOffice calc module, but could only find solutions like
[Copy every nth line from one sheet to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211062/copy-every-nth-line-from-one-sheet-to-another)
and some macro for OO that i was unable to adopt to my needs.
then I thought it might be more something for a cmd script, but i could not find a suitable example for that either.
what I was able to do is make a list of the lines i want in calc,and with help of:
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS($L$1,K3,1,,"Sheet1"))
where l1=1 and k3=3 it should result in sheet1.C1, and that solved it for me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You might get better answers if you clarify: how would you like to achieve this. i.e. in Excel, or programmatically (SO is about programming), in which language...? What exactly do you want to do - I cannot quite understand which lines to keep/skip. What is your problem, what have you tried so far, what went wrong? E.g. addressing dataframe rows in R? Can you give a wworking example - in your Q, it seems you just keep rows 2, 3, n1, n2 (n1 andn2 are not part of the "whole" dataset).

Comment: This sounds like a database application. Load the .csv file into a database (any database) and write SQL against it. I would not see this as a good application for cmd.exe .bat file scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice challenge. Here is a pure batch solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM following code to produce some data for testing:
(
echo date,hour,temp
echo 20181231,24,99
for /l %%a in (1,1,9) do @for /l %%b in (1,1,24) do @echo 2019010%%a,%%b,!random:~-2!
for /l %%a in (1,1,9) do @for /l %%b in (1,1,24) do @echo 2019011%%a,%%b,!random:~-2!
for /l %%a in (1,1,9) do @for /l %%b in (1,1,24) do @echo 2019012%%a,%%b,!random:~-2!
)>hourdata-test.csv


REM code to extract desired values
REM expected hour-pairs: 1,2 - 10,11 - 19,20 - 4,5 - 13,14 - 22,23 - 7,8 - 16,17 : repeat

(for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" hourdata-test.csv') do (
  set /a "x=%%a %% 9"
  if !x! == 3 echo %%b
  if !x! == 4 echo %%b
))>ninerdata.csv
```

The trick is to use the line numbers, calculate `Modulo 9` and then simply compare the resulting value. Skipping the first two lines is achieved by printing the modulo numbers 3 and 4.

A full year of data should take less than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would use R:

```
setwd(dir = "c:/...")                       # set working directory.
d <- read.csv("hourdata-2019.csv")          # read your datafile
rows <- c(2, 3, ...)                        # define the rows as needed, can be a formula
d[rows, ]                                   # will give you the modified dataset
write.csv(x = d, file = "hourdata-2019 out.csv")
```

If you prefer a Libre/Excel solution, you may expand on the link provided by yourself, possibly with two offset formulas for the first and second rows each, but this is possibly rather for the superuser forum.

Otherwise I am sure there is a wizard-like solution for Linux/bash/sed..., not sure about Win cmd.